# How to enable Author - Year in text using PhDbiblio-* style?

Tags: citing

I am using `\bibliographystyle{Latex/Classes/PhDbiblio-url2}` available at http://openwetware.org/wiki/LaTeX_template_for_PhD_thesis.

It requires the `natbib` package and I installed it as `\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}`.

My problem is: since I am using PhDbiblio-* style, it avoids the in-tex references to be [Fred et al. 1990]. I only can have number in-tex references as "[45]". Actually it seems to be compulsory to have "numbers" in this PhDbiblio-* style.

Any clues on how to stup/change the PhDbiblio-* style in order to show the in-tex referecne as [Fred et al. 1990]?

Comment: Can you not just pick a different style, for example `plainnat`, which is author-year rather than numeric?

Comment: Yes, I could but then I loose all the fancy config in PhDbiblio-url2 style. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Starting with a proper (author-year) base style and then adding some "fancy config" is much more feasible than starting with the proper "fancy config" and then trying to bend the (numeric) base style.

Comment: I tried that either, but it seems that my problem actually has nothing to do with the PhDbiblio-url2 style. It seems that some versions of natbib fail working with author-year argument.

Comment: In that case, add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're still interested in this topic, but here goes. Since you say that the .bst file can be used with the `natbib` package, have you tried issuing the command

```
\setcitestyle{authoryear,square,aysep={}}
```

after the `\usepackage{natbib}` command? Then, if you use the natbib's `\citep` command, you should hopefully get in-text citations formatted like `[Jones 1988]` and `[Smith et al. 2011]`. I must warn you that I haven't tried out this particular .bst file on any of my own papers, so I'm operating mostly on the basis of what the `natbib` documentation says. Happy TeXing!